Geometry Node understanding
This nodes can show the faces connected to a selected edge of a cube , but I do not understand why ... boolean value becoming float value are used in different context ... probably it is necessary for me understand to go deeply in the power of Blender Geo Nodes , thank you very much for an help

Connecting bool results and value to group output always 0 is showed also if 2 faces are showed

It is not clear what your question is. 3 quick notes : (1) If you use a boolean as a float, it will be interpreted as 0.0 for false, and 1.0 for true. (2) Index is a contextual node, it provides index of vertex, edge, face, ... depending on what it is plugged into. (3) You can Evaluate on Domain with boolean instead of float.

You should probably learn how to use the viewer node and the spreadsheet. A lot of these questions would be answered by that.

When you "evaluate on edge", you're getting a boolean result for that edge.
A boolean is either true (=1) or false (=0)
When you convert boolean to float, those are the values you get.
When you change a result from "edge domain" to "face domain", this result is interpolated.

A face has many edges, and only one of these edges evaluate to true (=1)
So the face result is 1/n where n is the number of edges

Faces with all edges = 0 have value = 0
Faces with one edge = 1 have value 1/n
Faces with all edges = 1 have value 1



So you're using a math trick to select faces whose value > 0, meaning at least one edge is different from 0.

In short...
Boolean to float:

True = 1
False = 0

Float to boolean:

<=0 = False
>0 = True

Changing domains interpolate the values.

Here, a viewer node can show you the interpolation:


In the spreadsheed, select faces
Notice the 0.25 values (they're 1/4 - each face has 4 edges)
Must use the original geometry because you're comparing with indices of the original geometry (after separating, the indices change)


Thank You Daniel , but why in the spread sheet no true value or float > 0 happens for the 2 faces ? if I connect to group output the values from last greater than node

These values will only appear in the spreadsheet if you use a "viewer" node or if you "store named attribute".

@MarcoGreco, see a viewer node showing the interpolated values in the edited answer

First, you select the edge of index 9 (Edge extrusion is a popular way of displaying selected edges, because as you can see there's no coloring of boolean edge attribute):

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Then you're making an implicit coercion of boolean to float (adding zero to show it has nothing to do with changing evaluation context):

Imgur mirror
The reason "Evaluate on Domain" node often uses float instead of boolean socket is that boolean domain interpolation doesn't always have a satisfying behavior.
If for whatever reason you're evaluating a field in a face corner context (e.g. "Distribute Points on Faces" evaluates selection in corner domain), but you still want to select an edge, you need to pass that through "Evaluate on Domain" node, because you don't want to select the face corner #9, you want to select the edge #9 (unfortunately on the GIF below the face corner #9 happens to be at one of the edge #9 ends, but this is just a coincidence):

Imgur mirror
You can notice there are overlapping "True" and "False" there, because 3 corners live in the same place (and sadly Blender isn't smart enough to offset captions towards face centers).
Likewise, the 2nd viewer displays both "0.5" and "0". But why "0.5"? When changing domains, the values have to somehow translated between them, which is called an interpolation. Aside from boolean type, it all* works the same: take the average of all connected elements of the domain you're switching from. Every face corner has only 2 connected edges (the vertical edge is shared by face corner's vertex, but is not a part of its face). Therefore one connected edge evaluates as 1, the other as 0, the average of the two is 0.5.
What you're doing is evaluate a field in edge domain, interpolate to face corner, and then interpolate again to the face domain chosen in "Separate Geometry" node. On above GIF the corners of the top face evaluated to these values:

0.5
0.5
0
0

So the average for the top face is ${0.5 + 0.5 + 0 + 0 \over 4} = {1 \over 4} = 0.25$:

Imgur mirror
Therefore this face will be selected with a node "Greater Than: 0" - which node doesn't need to be used because that's the float to boolean implicit coercion. Apparently in your case indices are different therefore your top face isn't selected.
* - as of the time of writing this answer

What tool do you use to make these gifs?

@DanielMöller ShareX
